# Populate json from integral accordion control

Tags: jquery

I am using integral UI accordion widget. On the click of the button i want to populate a json object.

here is the code http://jsbin.com/wiciwubaze/2/edit

If an accordion row is checked only that data should be added to the jSon object and it should be populate in the below format.

```
{
"name" : "Test App" 
"stores" : [{
    "storeName" : "Amazon AppStore",
    "storeNotes" : "Test Store Notes",
    "markets" : [1,2],
    "purchaseModels" : [1,2],
    "osVersions" : [
        {  
        "osId":"1",
        "versions":["2","11"]
        }
    ]
},{
    "storeName" : "Apple AppStore",
    "storeNotes" : "Test Store Notes",
    "markets" : [1,2],
    "purchaseModels" : [1,2],
    "osVersions" : [
        {  
        "osId":"12",
        "versions":["12","191"]
        }
    ]
}]
```

}

Just need help with getting started on how to iterate. And in the above json "versions":["12","191"] is a multi select dropdown that i can populate.

Need help with how to iterate using class name/id etc.

Comment: Give a class active to the current accordion, on save data click check which accordion is active. Check all the options and populate one object with it. Create a main one with only `name` and `stores`. After populating the options object push it to the main one inside stores. Have you tried that ?

Comment: for each checked accordion row i want to add the data to the object. If you see the jsbin i provided for example when the user selects multiple accordion checkboxes i want to add the data inside each accordion to the object. Not sure how to iterate, can you provide some initial reference of code.